# Matrices C++ imprimir 2 matrices y sumar sus bordes

Tags: c++, matrices

Desarrolle e implemente un programa que solicite el tamaño de una matriz cuadrada, y realice lo siguiente:

- Generar dos matrices cuadradas dinámicas con valores aleatorios enteros entre 1 y 5.
- Imprimir ambas matrices.
- Generar e imprimir una tercera matriz, también cuadrada. En cuyos bordes contenga la suma de cada elemento de las dos matrices anteriores. Los elementos que no estén ubicados en los bordes no se suman y en la tercera matriz tendrán el valor de cero.
- Generar e imprimir una cuarta matriz, también cuadrada. En donde la matriz haga un giro antihorario de 90 grados.
- Es necesario que utilice punteros y asignación dinámica de memoria
- No olvide liberar la memoria la final del programa.

El output debe ser este:

> ```
> Matriz 1:
> 4 2 3 1 4 1
> 2 3 5 2 3 3
> 1 5 4 2 1 2
> 3 2 2 4 3 5
> 3 1 3 4 3 1
> 5 3 3 4 5 3
>
> Matriz 2:
> 4 2 2 3 5 4
> 2 5 5 3 4 5
> 1 1 4 2 2 1
> 2 4 3 1 2 2
> 1 1 5 3 2 1
> 2 5 4 3 5 1
>
> Matriz 3 Resultado :
> 8 4 5 4 9 5
> 4 0 0 0 0 8
> 2 0 0 0 0 3
> 5 0 0 0 0 7
> 4 0 0 0 0 2
> 7 8 7 7 10 4
>
> Matriz 4 Resultado :
> 5 8 3 7 2 4
> 9 0 0 0 0 10
> 4 0 0 0 0 7
> 5 0 0 0 0 7
> 4 0 0 0 0 8
> 8 4 2 5 4 7
> ```

Si me ayudarían a saber porque no corre el código por favor, se los agradecería.

El código que he avanzado es este:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
void imprimir(int** pmatriz,int fc){
    for(int i=0;i<fc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fc;j++){
            cout<<setw(3)<<pmatriz[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void suma(int** pmatriz, int** pmatriz_2, int** pmatriz_3, int fc){
    for(int i=0;i<fc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fc;j++){
            pmatriz_3[i][j] = pmatriz[0][j]+pmatriz_2[0][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<fc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fc;j++){
            pmatriz_3[i][j] = pmatriz[i][0]+pmatriz_2[i][0];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<fc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fc;j++){
            pmatriz_3[fc][j] = pmatriz[fc][j]+pmatriz_2[fc][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<fc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<fc;j++){
            pmatriz_3[i][fc] = pmatriz[i][fc]+pmatriz_2[i][fc];
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int fc;
    int **pmatriz = nullptr;
    int **pmatriz_2 = nullptr;
    int **pmatriz_3 = nullptr;
    srand(time(nullptr));
    cout<<"Orden de la matriz cuadrada:";cin>>fc;
    for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++) {
        pmatriz[i] = new int[fc];
        for (int j = 0; j < fc; j++) {
            pmatriz[i][j] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++) {
        pmatriz_2[i] = new int[fc];
        for (int j = 0; j < fc; j++) {
            pmatriz_2[i][j] = 1 + rand() % (6 - 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++) {
        pmatriz_3[i] = new int[fc];
        for (int j = 0; j < fc; j++) {
            pmatriz_3[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    imprimir(pmatriz, fc);
    imprimir(pmatriz_2, fc);
    suma(pmatriz, pmatriz_2, pmatriz_3, fc);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Porque no me corre el código... gracias.

Comment: "*no me corre el código*" es una descripción bastante vaga ¿no compila el código? ¿compila pero falla en ejecución? ¿Compila y no falla en ejecución pero los resultados son diferentes a lo que esperas? ¿qué errores de compilación o de ejecución obtienes? ¿Qué datos introduces y qué datos esperabas obtener?

Comment: Compila pero falla en la ejecución

Comment: Bien, estamos más cerca de poder entender el problema que encuentras ¿Qué fallos encuentras durante la ejecución? ¿Se ve algo en pantalla?

Answer (score 0):

El programa se cuelga (con *segmentation fault* en Linux) porque nunca reservas memoria para el arreglo de punteros e intentas acceder a una dirección de memoria que no deberías.

Entonces, antes de hacer nada con el arreglo de punteros, reserva memoria.

```
pmatriz = new int*[fc];
pmatriz_2 = new int*[fc];
pmatriz_3 = new int*[fc];
```

---

La función `suma` también tiene un problema relacionado con la memoria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < fc; j++){
        pmatriz_3[fc][j] = pmatriz[fc][j] + pmatriz_2[fc][j]; // Aquí
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < fc; j++){
        pmatriz_3[i][fc] = pmatriz[i][fc] + pmatriz_2[i][fc]; // Y aquí
    }
}
```

La posición del último elemento es el tamaño del arreglo menos 1 porque el primero es el **0**. `fc` es el tamaño del arreglo así que está accediendo al elemento siguiente al último.

Lo correcto es:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < fc; j++){
        pmatriz_3[fc - 1][j] = pmatriz[fc - 1][j] + pmatriz_2[fc - 1][j];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < fc; j++){
        pmatriz_3[i][fc - 1] = pmatriz[i][fc - 1] + pmatriz_2[i][fc - 1];
    }
}
```